# Is it possible to install node.js in IIS7?

Tags: node.js, iis-7, webserver

Is there a way to install node.js in IIS7?

I have very little experience with node.js but the idea of writing server-side JavaScript intrigues me.

Comment: check this project [tjanczuk/iisnode - GitHub](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) and this tutorial [Creating a quick Todo listing app on Windows using IIS7, Node.js and Mongodb : Amazedsaint's .net journal](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/09/creating-10-minute-todo-listing-app-on.html)

Comment: There are some good articles on this now: [Installing and Running node.js applications within IIS on Windows - Are you mad?](http://blogs.iis.net/shanselman/archive/2011/08/28/installing-and-running-node-js-applications-within-iis-on-windows-are-you-mad.aspx)<br />
[Hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html)<br />
http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/09/creating-10-minute-todo-listing-app-on.html ... even a github project with some samples: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/tree/master/src/samples <br />
https://gi

Comment: This question is better suited on http://serverfault.com rather than StackOverflow as it is not programming related.

Comment: msft have provide a EXE called IISNODE that will make you able to run node on your IIS server as well as IIS express.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do it...but it's still not going to be as easy as you'd hope. :-)

The [github wiki for iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki) lists many benefits:

- Process management.
- Side by side with other content types
- Scalability on multi-core servers
- Integrated debugging
- Auto-update
- Access to logs over HTTP
- Minimal changes to node.js application code
- Integrated management experience
- Others

The first stable build on node.js for windows was released earlier this month.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2011/11/07/first-stable-build-of-nodejs-on-windows-released.aspx

More information on hosting IIS on Windows can be found [here](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html) and [here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).

---

**Prerequisites for using**

- Windows
- IIS 7.x with IIS Management Tools
- [URL rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)
- [Latest node.js build for Windows](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9784334)

  - You can also do it manually by downloading node.exe from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/#download) and saving to %programfiles%\nodejs on a 32 bit system or `%programfiles(x86)%\nodejs` on a 64 bit system
- Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package for [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) or [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632) (skip this if you install Visual Studio; on x64 systems you need to install both x86 and x64 if you intend to use IIS Express/WebMatrix)

**Installing for IIS 7.x**

- Install iisnode for IIS 7.x: [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9784330) or [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9784331) - choose bitness matching your system
- To set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call `%programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat`
- Go to `http://localhost/node`

**Installing for IIS Express/WebMatrix**

- [Install WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)
- [Install iisnode for IIS Express 7.x](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9784329)
- [Install node.js templates for WebMatrix](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/Node.js-Site-Templates-for-WebMatrix/downloads)
- Open WebMatrix, choose "Site from folder", enter `%localappdata%\iisnode\www`, start the site, and play with the iisnode samples, or
- Use node.js templates to get started quickly with an Express application or a skeleton Hello World

Comment: Scaling across multiple cores sounds like a huge win..  I've always thought the single-threadedness of node.js was kinda a dealbreaker for certain apps.

Comment: FYI: The [roadmap for v0.8](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nodejs/eVBOYiI_O_A/discussion) states that they are working on "Isolates. Node will allow users to spawn 'child processes' that actually run in a thread."

Comment: I'd love to know why I received a down vote. Is something not correct?

Comment: Thanks so much for all this (wish I would have found it sooner!). Is iisnode v 0.2.7 still the latest version for iis 7 and earlier? Also, I believe there is now built in functionality for node.js apps in iis 7.5 and above [here](http://gotdibbs.ghost.io/ghost-on-windows-with-a-reverse-proxy/)